# Continuous connection retry attempts of ibm mq consumer resulting into memory leak after a while resulting into jvm crash. How to resolve this?

Tags: spring-boot, memory-leaks, ibm-mq

Take a instance why IBM Mq instance goes down. Now message consumer in my application retries to connect after fixed delay of 5000ms.

```
2020-10-13 08:37:27.178 ERROR 81638 [] --- [org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway#1.replyListener-1] o.s.i.j.JmsOutboundGateway$GatewayReplyListenerContainer - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'null' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=4, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'X' with connection mode 'Client' and host name '10.158.144.79(1417)'.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE').
2020-10-13 08:41:05.546 ERROR 81638 [] --- [org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsOutboundGateway#0.replyListener-1] o.s.i.j.JmsOutboundGateway$GatewayReplyListenerContainer - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'null' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=3, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'X' with connection mode 'Client' and host name '10.158.144.79(1417)'.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE').
```

This results in memory leak after a while and jvm crashes. How can we resolve this?
Below is how i am building connection factory

```
@Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws JMSException {
    MQQueueConnectionFactory mqconnectionfactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    mqconnectionfactory.setHostName(properties.getHost());
    mqconnectionfactory.setChannel(properties.getAppChannel());
    mqconnectionfactory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(properties.getPort()));
    mqconnectionfactory.setQueueManager(properties.getQueueManager());
    mqconnectionfactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
    mqconnectionfactory.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
    mqconnectionfactory.setStringProperty(properties.PROPERTY_USER_ID, mqProperties.getUsername());
 return wrapConnectionFactoryWithCachingConnectionFactory(mqconnectionfactory);
    }


    private ConnectionFactory wrapConnectionFactoryWithCachingConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
            CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(20);
            cachingConnectionFactory.setCacheConsumers(false);
    
    
            return cachingConnectionFactory;
        }
```

OutboundGatway configuration :

```
 <int-jms:outbound-gateway request-channel="getBrandingSerializedEntryPointResponseChannel" reply-channel="getBrandingDeserializedEntryPointResponseChannel"
                                  requires-reply="true" correlation-key="JMSCorrelationID"
                                  request-destination-name="${fbu.request.banding.queue}"
                                  reply-destination-name="${fbu.response.banding.queue}"
                                  receive-timeout="${fbu.queue.receive.timeout}"
                                  connection-factory="brandingConnectionFactory">


            <int-jms:reply-listener recovery-interval="${mq.connection.recovery.interval}"/>
        </int-jms:outbound-gateway>
```

Comment: Can i use com.ibm.mq.cfg.TCP.Connect_Timeout property to close the thread?

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention which IBM MQ client version you are using. There are MQ java client fixes like [IT29114](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IT29114) or [IT26789](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IT26789). Maybe you experience one of them.

Comment: I am using vesion 9.2.0.0

Comment: <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
<artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
<version>9.2.0.0</version>

Comment: Ok, then above to bugs are not your problem. Reading the [Outbound Gateway](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html#jms-outbound-gateway) documentation, certain configuration can lead to out-of-memory conditions. Can you update your question with your Spring Integration configuration?

Comment: I was able to minimize reconnect intervals by increasing the recovery time, but still as i am not able to overwrite the max attempts, it goes into out of memory after some time

Comment: CacheConsumer is also set to false, updated in question

Comment: You use a `brandingConnectionFactory` in your outbound gateway, but you did not show as it's configuration. Is it the same as the one you show? Did you try to not use a `CachingConnectionFactory` at all?